# Bash: Wait until user is fully logged in in X

Tags: bash

I have a bash script, started daily by anacron, that needs some user input from time to time. This should be done via graphical dialog boxes, like kdialog offers.

There are three options to consider:

- "Yes, start the task today" -> run task
- "No, do not start the task today" -> exit script
- Error, User not fully logged in to X -> retry in 1 minute

Here's my code so far (the script is run as the user in question):

```
while ! kdialog --title "Task $DATE" --msgbox "Please make preparations for today's task and press OK"
do
   logger -t task "waiting for display to become available"
   sleep 1m
done
```

This works, except that I do not see any option to use a YesNo-dialog AND distinguish between the button click "No, don't start today" and "Error, the X server is not yet available for the user" -- because kdialog returns the exit code 1 in BOTH cases.

I thought about using a different program to check whether the X server is usable already, but I did not come up with an idea which to use. Anyone's got a better idea? (Using Kubuntu 10.04 with KDE4, if that info is needed...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

```
xprop -root
```

**xprop** come with **x11-utils** package and most likely installed together with X11...

Also check **SEE ALSO** section in **man 1 xprop**:

```
SEE ALSO
       X(7), xdpyinfo(1), xwininfo(1), xdriinfo(1), glxinfo(1), xvinfo(1)
```

Comment: checking env for $DISPLAY does the same thing except faster and requires no extra programs.

Comment: @technosaurus. You are bad... Anacron running from **init** script and **DISPLAY** env var is not populated from X client.... And -1 for my -1))

Comment: sorry for waiting that long with the checkmark ... but I wrote this script for my Dad, who does not use the computer very often. Finally -- yesterday, he told me that it works consistently and without failure all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use any standard X program. , I suggest `xdpyinfo` because it is text only.

Answer (score -1):

Consider making it an [autostart entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html) instead, since 1) you probably don't actually need it started *daily*, and 2) you'll need to find the display otherwise.